# OAuth2 authentication for CakePHP 3

Tags: php, cakephp, oauth, oauth-2.0, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to setup **OAuth2** authentication for a **REST API** I am writing in **CakePHP 3**. Everything I could find on the topic however has been only for CakePHP 2. I tried **[this particular plugin](https://github.com/thomseddon/cakephp-oauth-server)**, but I couldn't even install it.

Comment: The question is way too broad to be answered. In case you have any specific problems, please describe them. Also check **https://github.com/thomseddon/cakephp-oauth-server/issues/58**

Comment: Particular question: Is there an OAuth2 plugin/library for CakePHP 3? From what I saw in your link, implementation is in progress, but still not publicly available.

Comment: "_Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow [...]_", that's another closing reason, just so you know. That being said, I don't know any other such library/plugin.

Comment: https://github.com/uafrica/oauth-server i have used this method . for OAuth in cakePHP 3 but it not even installed.if you find the answer please share it in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34607175/how-to-use-an-oauth-in-cake-php-3.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a oauth2 server for cakephp3, you can check https://libraries.io/packagist/uafrica%2Foauth-server out. I actually did not use it yet, but will give it a try in the future